# pyodbc & MS SQL Server - "No results. Previous SQL was not a query."

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc to retrieve data from a Microsoft SQL Server. The query is of the following form

```
SET NOCOUNT ON --Ignore count statements

CREATE TABLE mytable ( ... )

EXEC some_stored_procedure
INSERT mytable

--Perform some processing...

SELECT *
FROM mytable
```

The stored procedure performs some aggregation over values that contain `NULLs` such that warnings of the form `Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.` are issued. This results in pyodbc failing to retrieve data with the error message `No results. Previous SQL was not a query.`

I have tried to disable the warnings by setting `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF`. However, the query then fails with the error message `Heterogeneous queries require the ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS options to be set for the connection. This ensures consistent query semantics. Enable these options and then reissue your query.`.

Is it possible to

- disable the warnings
- or have pyodbc ignore the warnings?

Note that I do not have permissions to change the stored procedure.

Comment: Don't you need semicolons between your statements? `;`? I'm genuinely asking. I don't know.

Comment: @JoeFrambach: No, semicolons are not required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the results of the query in a temporary table and execute the statement as two queries:

```
with pyodbc.connect(connection_string) as connection:
    connection.execute(query1)            #Do the work
    result = connection.execute(query2)   #Select the data
    data = result.fetchall()              #Retrieve the data
```

The first query does the heavy lifting and is of the form

```
--Do some work and execute complicated queries that issue warning messages

--Store the results in a temporary table
SELECT some, column, names
INTO #datastore
FROM some_table
```

The second query retrieves the data and is of the form

```
SELECT * FROM #datastore
```

Thus, all warning messages are issued upon execution of the first query. They do not interfere with data retrieval during the execution of the second query.

Comment: The above answer from Till doesn't work as the second query doesn't know what that table is even though the connection hasn't been dropped. However, if you use a global temp table, it works. eg: ##datastore

Comment: That seems rather odd as the scope of temporary tables is per-session (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) and not per-query. Are you dropping your session but keeping your connection alive? I would caution against using global temporary tables because multiple users executing the same query at the same time could cause conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

I have had some luck mitigating this error by flipping ansi_warnings on and off just around the offending view or stored proc.

```
/* vw_someView aggregates away some nulls and presents warnings that blow up pyodbc */
set ANSI_WARNINGS off
select *
into #my_temp
from vw_someView
set ANSI_WARNINGS on

/* rest of query follows */
```

This assumes that the entity that produces the aggregate warning doesn't also require warnings to be turned on.  If it complains, it probably means that the entity itself has a portion of code like this that requires a toggle of the ansi_warnings (or a rewrite to eliminate the aggregation.)

One caviat is that I've found that this toggle still returns the "heterogeneous" warning if I try to run it as a cross-server query.  Also, while debugging, it's pretty easy to get into a state where the ansi_warnings are flipped off when you don't realize it and you start getting heterogeneous errors for seemingly no reason.  Just run the "set ANSI_WARNINGS on" line by itself to get yourself back into a good state.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing is to add try: except: block

```
sql="sp_help stored_procedure;"
print(">>>>>executing {}".format(sql))
next_cursor=cursor.execute(sql)
while next_cursor:
try:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    while row:
        print(row)
        row = cursor.fetchone()
except Exception as my_ex:
    print("stored procedure returning non-row {}".format(my_ex))
next_cursor=cursor.nextset()
```